# How to convert a dynamic string to a date

Tags: postgresql

How do I convert a dynamic string to a date in PostgreSQL, I have tried the below?

```
select Extract(year from CURRENT_DATE)||'-04'||'-01'
    
    select * 
    from table a
    where a.timestamp::date=Extract(year from CURRENT_DATE)||'-04'||'-01'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `make_date()` for this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=389d21d180534b112d968bb74f51a060)

```
SELECT
    make_date(
        extract(year from current_date)::int,
        4,
        1
    )
```

Of course, you can use this in the `WHERE` clause, as well:

```
WHERE make_date(extract(year from current_date)::int, 4, 1) = ...
```

Comment: Good health to you